# I want to make a calculator but i have TypeError how can i solve this

Tags: python, typeerror

How can i solve the TypeError

I tried this:

```
print("Multiplication Calculator for Kids")

onenum = input("Enter a number")
twonum = input("Enter a second number")
calc = onenum * twonum

print(calc)
```

Comment: make them `int()`. `input()` returns string.

Comment: `onenum = int(input("Enter a number"))
twonum = int(input("Enter a second number"))`

Comment: built-in input function take string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the input value is a string. And you cannot perform operations on strings. You need to convert it to integer first.

```
print("Multiplication Calculator for Kids")

onenum = int(input("Enter a number"))
twonum = int(input("Enter a second number"))
calc = onenum * twonum

print(calc)
```

Or you can use `eval()` to evaluate string values.

```
print("Multiplication Calculator for Kids")

onenum = input("Enter a number")
twonum = input("Enter a second number")
calc = eval(f"{onenum} * {twonum}")

print(calc)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use
onenum = input("Enter a number")

datatype of onenum is String
you much cast onenum to int by
onenum  = int(onenum)